# Entire function that is a polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I came across the following exercise while studying for a qual:  Suppose that $f$ is an entire function such that $|f (z)| \geq 1$ whenever $|z|\geq 1$. Show that $f$ is a polynomial.

I'm not sure how to begin this exercise. I had thought maybe using the fact that f is a not identically zero, it must have a finite number of zeros on the unit disk. From there I was hoping to invert f and divide by it's zeros so I had a bounded entire function g. Then I had wanted to invoke liouville. But I not so sure these final steps are good ones.

Comment: Sounds like an excellent plan. Divide out the zeroes before inverting, though.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The singularity at $\infty$ is a pole.  What does the Laurent series look like?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently $f$ has at most finitely many zeros, and all in the open unit disk.

Say $f(z)=g(z)p(z)$, where $p(z)=(z-z_1)\cdots(z-z_n)$ is a polynomial with all the roots of $f$
and $g$ not vanishing, and of course, $g$ is also entire, and so is $h=1/g$.

Also, $|p(z)|\le c|z|^n$, for all $|z|\ge 1$, for some $c\ge 1$.

Now we have that 
$$1 \le |\,f(z)|=|g(z)||p(z)|\le c|g(z)|,$$ 
for $|z|\ge 1,$ 
and hence
$$
c\ge \frac{1}{|g(z)|}=|h(z)|, \quad\text{when $|z|\ge 1$}
$$
Thus $h$ is bounded and entire and hence constant, say $h(z)=a$, 
where $a\in\mathbb C$, with $|a|\le c$, and finally
$$
f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{a}.
$$

Comment: $ 1 \le |\,f(z)|=|g(z)||p(z)|\le c|g(z)|, $ this part dosent make any sense to me, Iam assuming you have used $|p(z)|\le c|z|^n$ but where does the $|z|^n$ go?